# Showing $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x_{n}=y_{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ of all sequences $x=\left \{ x_{1},x_{2},... \right \}$ of real numbers.

Define the function $d:\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\times \mathbb{R}^{\infty}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by:

$d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1 }^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^{n}} \frac{\left | x_{n}-y_{n} \right |}{1 + \left | x_{n}-y_{n} \right |}$.

I want to show that $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x_{n}=y_{n}$.

I have $$d(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1 }^{\infty } \frac{1}{2^{n}} \frac{\left | x_{n}-y_{n} \right |}{1 + \left | x_{n}-y_{n} \right |}=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \frac{|x_{n}-y_{n}|}{1+|x_{n}-y_{n}|} = 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  |x_{n} - y_{n}| = 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x_{n} = y_{n}$$.

Is Step 2 legitimate?

Comment: How is $1/2 + 1/2 + \ldots$ left if $x_n = y_n$. If $x_n=y_n$, then all the numerators are zero right?

Comment: Oops. My bad! Yes, you're right I was being sloppy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say so. A sum of non-negative reals is 0 iff every term was itself zero. This is easy to prove independently.

Comment: How would one prove such a fact?